# Is Core Data migration required when no change in Core Data entities?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I have a app on app store & we need to update app with some new feature but our Core Data structure is same as the old one.

So is the core data migration required thing to do with every new release of app ?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not required to update version. Only when you need to update if you change/add entity/attribute/etc. of core data.

Answer (score 1):

The only time you need to migrate is when the definition of your models change.

This is required, because otherwise CoreData would not know how to handle your new "scheme" of data and how to apply the old saved data to it.

But, this is also just required if you want your data to be really persistent throughout app versions. If it is data which can be cleared after your definition changes, you can simply clear your data store and apply the new model. This applies to offline caches for example.